# SO remote jobs: Include preferred timezones in email alerts

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

I see a remote job alert I like, and I click on it. The first sentence is either:

Preferred country x

or

preferred timezone x

I immediately close the tab, because it's pointless to continue reading if you don't meet those criteria

- It would be nice if I don't get alerts at all about jobs that I can't apply for (An option to customize the alert I like to receive and to opt-out of receiving alerts about jobs I cannot apply for).
- It would be nice if I can read some excerpt about the job from within the email so that I don't have to click on the link only to close it.

Comment: _Preferred_ doesn't mean they won't consider those outside the timezone or country right, just like if they said they preferred knowledge of technology X if you're applying for technology Y?

Comment: @Tas agreed but I'd still like to see the features mentioned in my question because personally i feel there's a little chance for me to be the outsider. All companies on jobs.so are great companies and all the candidates are so great. I don't want to apply for a job that gives me a little chance of being accepted

Comment: i support this. this is the case for most of the ads. also can they ads target the people on the correct country, if possible.

Comment: This would be good. Ultimately, SE makes money by actually hooking up job seekers with jobs. Showing people jobs which they can't qualify for is counterproductive. The more jobs which are shown which the user can't apply for the more likely it is that the user stops looking at the possibilities, due to the belief that looking is a waste of time.

Answer (score 1):

I like this feature request, but it has to be considered carefully. Let me play devil's advocate. If the job ad says, *preferred* country, and not required country, then how do you know that you're wasting your time by applying?

And, even if you do really know beyond doubt that these jobs won't work for you, is that really true for others who are, similarly, receiving ads for a different country? There's a danger that by including incomplete info with an ad link, job seekers could summarily dismiss a job without looking at the details — details which might lead them to change their mind about applying.

Comment: I asked for two features: 1- filters: those will work if you apply them, no one is forced to filter out jobs, options are always good and everyone has his own preferences. 2- Email excerpts are always good in every possible scenario, reading an excerpt before clicking can't be bad.

Comment: I'd like to play devil's devil's advocate here. In my experience (personal and discussed with others), it's like when a guy says *I prefer women*. In a vast majority (read: all or almost all) cases *preferred* means *required*. It might be my Swedish talking where we tend to be indirect but it seems like *you might want to bring an umbrella* meaning *it's raining all kinds of pets and you better stay home*.

Comment: @KonradViltersten For country specifically, that may or may not be the case; But in many cases, everything's negotiable (and this feature request extends to more than just country). The best candidate to apply & interview will be accepted, even if that person is under-qualified. In some cases, the role will be redefined to match what they *can* do. I myself have seen that happen more than once.

Comment: @Lynob When I read your question, I don't see a request for an optional filter *preference.* I see a request to change the filters for everyone. I'd be far less concerned about that. (If an individual filters themselves out from jobs that they're interested in and qualified for, that's largely their own responsibility to sort out; unless that happened often enough, it would not be a concern to SO's bottom line, either.)

Comment: @jpaugh I added a sentence which I hope it clarifies what I meant, if my question still needs clarification, please feel free to edit it.

Comment: @jpaugh I see. Perhaps it's just me being unlucky getting foot in on the US market that way. For some reason, I've failed to get into work for the Americans the last years (remotely, that is). It would suit me great because I prefer working evenings/nights due to medical condition. But I got a no-no every time...

Comment: @KonradViltersten It probably varies greatly depending on what part of the market you're job-searching in: if there are lots of qualified candidates, then of course country is going to matter a great deal. But, I've no experience with job-searching in another country, and you may be right that it isn't so fluid. At any rate, best of luck to you!

Comment: I agree. Companies are posting a lot of supposedly Remote jobs but only for US residents. I also find myself wasting time seeing jobs that are tagged as Remote but inside they say US only. There should be an additional parameter in the job to specify a hard location requirement. In summary, remote doesn't mean anywhere in the world and the current Jobs model doesn't address this.

Comment: @jpaugh it's not always a preference but a requirement from the company. Remote jobs but the person needs to be in X country (usually the US). There must be a way for us to weed these listings out of the results.

Comment: @SergioPulgarin Wouldn't it be great if there were a way to filter out hiring manager who were communicating poorly? Sounds like an example of that to me.

Comment: @jpaugh What you are saying would make sense if these were few isolated cases. They are not.